# Going from listen and fork to xinetd

Tags: c, sockets, xinetd

I have a piece of C network software that currently works in listen and fork mode. It's listening on some server socket and accepts incoming connection. Then it calls the core server function providing the new accepted socket.

Now I'm trying to make that software also work behind xinetd (depending on some runtime parameter). I tried to directly call the core server function providing file descriptor 0 instead of an accepted socket, but this method is just not working. The program immediately stops with a SIG_PIPE.

Is there any obvious reason for such behavior ? My core function performs some low level socket calls and signal handling. Is that supposed to work behind xinetd ?

Comment: Are you specifying `wait = no` in the `xinetd` configuration for your service?  If you don't, it will pass a duplicate of the listening socket rather than the accepted socket, requiring your service to perform the `accept()`.

Comment: yes, I'm specifying wait = no, but I should indeed try change my program behavior to perform the accept itself, may be it will solve the issues I have that seems to be socket related.

Comment: That should be fine then, with `wait = no` you should be passed the socket returned from `accept()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not absolutely certain but not everything you can do on a socket handle also works with ordinary file handles.  For a start, you can't write to stdin.  Also some system calls probably need a socket e.g. `recv()`.

**Edit**

Another possibility:  does your server process close stdin as part of its start up?

Comment: isn't xinetd supposed to provide a socket to called services ?

Comment: @kriss: Maybe.  I was assuming that xinetd created a pipe to talk to the back end server, but it would be more sensible for it to just to replace stdin with the socket descriptor I guess.

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to read xinetd source code to get a definitive answer, and no my process does not close stdin on startup (well, it does not close it when called with inetd option).

Comment: @kriss: I've already had a look at the source and you are right.